# Calling Java methods with React locally

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, api, jsp

How can i create a full web application with Java and React without having to create a rest API, not even a private API with username:password authentication.

I want it to be as it is created with JSP.

Is it possible call Java methods with react locally ?
Or even creating a restfull API that can only be called locally

Thank you

Comment: Java is running on your server, JavaScript is running in your browser client, so no, you can't run the Java locally in your browser client. If you're using JSP, chances are it's not that hard to add REST support for your React client code to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to communicate with Java in a client library such as React without having to create a HTTP API.
But you could make one and add a bit of extra layer of security to ensure that only your application could call your Java API by checking the remote address of each call and verifying that's the caller is indeed your server.

You can do this in Java using the `getRemoteAddr()` method from the `HttpServletRequest` object.

The best way to do this is to create a filter class that map all the API links and verify the remote address in each calls and then decide if it should allow it or not.

Here's an example:

```
import javax.servlet.*;  

public class RequestFilter implements Filter{  

  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}  

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,  
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        String callerIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
        if(callerIp.equalsIgnoreCase("MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS")) {
          chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        else {
          ((HttpServletResponse)res).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access denied !");
          return;
        }  
    }

    public void destroy() {}  
}
```

Replace "MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS" with your server ip.

And to map all the calls, set the filter tag in your web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myPackage.requestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This should satisfy your need, but if you found another way please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

the first request is no, as far as I'm aware. But as for the local rest api, I know most web servers can check CORS headers and restrict to only serve certain origins on answering requests.  So whichever JRE Web Server you're using, check it's API for accessing the origin in the request header, and route those to the rest code.